# Some BizTalk Receive Locations are disabled after server reboot

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

It is found that some BizTalk Receive Locations are disabled after server reboot (BizTalk server and SQL Server are separately installed to different physical servers)

Is there any idea on this scenario? Due to the boot sequence or other issues?

Comment: Can you please provide us with some more information on the type of receive location? What adapter are they using? What URI? etc... for example: it could be FILE adapter pointing to an external share.

Comment: Yes, file adapter pointing to the external share, which is in the sql server also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that, once you enable the receive locations manually, they are working correctly.

Typically, when FILE receive locations fail while pointing to an external server/share, it is because they are no longer available.

Make sure that, during the night, there are no network issues, planned/unplanned downtime of the share (= here your SQL server). A BizTalk receive location will retry to access a share for quite a while before disabling itself. Check the event log(s) for more information. You would want to look for errors/warnings there indicating an issue with connectivity between BizTalk and SQL.

Another issue might be that there are too many connections between your BizTalk server and SQL server. You can provide a maximum number of connections in the FILE share properties.

Also, you could try this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/235032/intermittent-connection-to-windows-7-shared-folder-from-windows-xp-workstations

It describes a potential fix for optimizing throughput for file sharing, although it depends on your operating system.